# при переходе на другую страницу выводяться куки ранее поставленые, а не перезаписаные

Tags: php, cookie, авторизация

Создаю куки:
`setcookie("login", "lalala", time() + 6400, "/");`

Далее вывожу их, перезаписываю и ставлю новые:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'.$_COOKIE['login'].'");</script>';
$_COOKIE['login'] = $login;
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'.$_COOKIE['login'].'");</script>';
echo '<script type="text/javascript">showCookie();</script>';
```

Всё работает, вывело поставленные, но.. далее идёт переход на новую страницу, где нужно вывести уже новые(не создаю снова):

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['login']))
   {
      echo $_COOKIE['login'];
   }
```

и почему то отображаються заданые в самом начале... Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что надо [читать документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php). setcookie() после echo не работают, это ограничение http-протокола.

Comment: так они же перезаписались и вывелись новые, я про то, что выводяться на другой странице снова первоначальные

Comment: Это они в php изменились. А в браузер они попасть уже не могут никак, если на экран произведен любой вывод, включая html

Comment: я уже это понял, спасибо) Но вот тогда возникает вопрос, как мне записать переменную(в которую я записал значение поля) в куку?

Comment: Все манипуляции с куками - до вывода на экран. И все.

Comment: Если ответ оказался полезен, его стоит отметить галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться другим пользователям, которые будут искать ответ на похожий вопрос.